# error using astype when NaN exists in a dataframe

Tags: pandas

```
df
     A     B  
0   a=10   b=20.10
1   a=20   NaN
2   NaN    b=30.10
3   a=40   b=40.10
```

I tried :

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
df['B'] = df['B'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

And:

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Firstly `NaN` can only be represented by float so you can't cast to `int` in that case, second if you have mixed dtypes for instance string and some other thing then using ``str.extract` will fail, although mixed dtypes are supported, it's not a good idea as it leads to errors. You should decide what the final dtype should be and replace the missing values that makes sense to you

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If some values in column are missing (`NaN`) and then converted to numeric, always `dtype` is `float`. You cannot convert values to `int`. Only to `float`, because `type` of `NaN` is `float`.

```
print (type(np.nan))
<class 'float'>
```

See [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions) how convert values if at least one `NaN`:

> integer    > cast to float64

If need int values you need replace `NaN` to some `int`, e.g. `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and then it works perfectly:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
df['B'] = df['B'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
     A    B
0   10   20
1   20  NaN
2  NaN   30
3   40   40

df1 = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
    A   B
0  10  20
1  20   0
2   0  30
3  40  40

print (df1.dtypes)
A    int32
B    int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 35):

From **pandas >= 0.24** there is now a **built-in pandas integer**. 
This does allow integer nan's, so you don't need to fill na's. 
Notice the capital in `'Int64'` in the code below. 
This is the pandas integer, instead of the numpy integer.

You need to use: `.astype('Int64')`

So, do this:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype('float').astype('Int64')
df['B'] = df['B'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype('float').astype('Int64')
```

More info on pandas integer na values:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions