# How to validate mobile number

Tags: python, pandas

i have df like this

```
   Contact Number
0   
1   NaN
2   6363887122.0
3   6363887122.0
```

I WANT THIS

```
    Contact Number  Status_contactNUmber   Invalid_contactNUmber
0                       Blank/Null                 True
1   NaN                 Blank/Null           True             
2   6363887122           Valid               False
3   6363887122           Valid               False
```

I try with this

```
def contactNumber(ele):
    if (pd.isna(ele) or (ele=='')):
        return ("Blank/Null",True)
    elif re.search(r'^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$',ele):
#     elif ele.str.contains(r'^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$'):
        return ("Valid",False)
    else:
        return ("invalid",True)
df[['Status_contactNUmber','Invalid_contactNUmber']] = df['Contact Number'].apply(contactNumber).tolist()
```

but give the Error because Contact Number column in `Float` type

Comment: Use `df["Contact Number"].astype(int)` to get those values as integers.

Comment: for null/blank not work

Comment: This has previously been answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550746/error-using-astype-when-nan-exists-in-a-dataframe/41550787). I would suggest you use the `fillna()` method to replace NaNs with invalid values. Or you can use pandas' **Int64** which does allow NaNs as mentioned in the post linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `0` you see at top of your `df's index` is actually the name of the index, and not the first row. First row in your `df` starts from `index = 1` (the **NaN** value). You can also understand it by the fact that if **Contact Number** column is of type **Float**, then how can it have a `""` value? (It will have **NaN**, just like it has there at `index = 1`).

I confirmed this by copying your df and checking its index (see  the name **'0'** and index starting from **1**):

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')
>>> df.index
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='0')
```

So now coming to what you want, you can do this by handling it in your function. Just convert the `ele` to **int** type first to remove **`.0`** from phone numbers and then convert to **str** type for regex matching:

```
def contactNumber(ele):
    if (pd.isna(ele)):
        return ("Blank/Null",True)
    elif re.search(r'^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$', str(int(ele))):
#     elif ele.str.contains(r'^([0]|\+91)?[6789]\d{9}$'):
        return ("Valid",False)
    else:
        return ("invalid",True)
```

You don't need the `(ele=='')` condition, because as stated, `float` type columns will not have blank strings.

**Output:**

```
>>> df[['Status_contactNUmber','Invalid_contactNUmber']] = df['Contact Number'].apply(contactNumber).tolist()
>>> df
   Contact Number Status_contactNUmber  Invalid_contactNUmber
0                                                            
1             NaN           Blank/Null                   True
2      6363887122              Valid                    False
3      6363887122              Valid                    False
```

Answer (score 0):

please change your column type string from float

Comment: Then but then Going to invalid bcz regex not match