# Pandas , remove unnecessary row values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset. It contains , some random "-" values for the tail rows. Due to which , I'm not able to convert the datatypes of the columns. How can I delete such values of "-"  using pandas ?

```
df2 = df2.drop(df2[df2["Inns"] == "-" or df2["NO"] == "-" or df2["Runs"] == "-" or df2["HS"] == "-" or df2["Ave"] == "-" or df2["BF"] == "-" or df2["SR"] == "-" or df2["100"] == "-" or df2["50"] == "-" or df2[0]=="-"].index)
```

df2

This is what I've used and below is the error I'm getting :

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Please help me remove it.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore errors when converting datatypes with the [pandas.DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method using the **errors** argument.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'col': 22},
                   {'col': '-'}])

df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

If what you want is to convert to **float** you can use [pandas.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace the **"-"** values with **np.nan** or **math.nan** and convert without issue.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col': 22},
                   {'col': '-'}])
df = df.replace('-', math.nan)
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
```

If what you want is to convert to **int** the second solution won't work and you have to replace **"-"** with **0**. For more info see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550787/6757036).

Edit:
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580754/6757036) you can convert to integers using the built-in pandas integer type.

```
import math
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'col': 22},
                   {'col': '-'}])
df = df.replace('-', math.nan)
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('Int64')
```